# Cancellation of sound coming out from speaker while recording?

Tags: audio, circuit-design

I am designing an embedded device for my personal project. It has a speaker which plays voice received from remote location and also records voice using a microphone while playing back the sound. The recorded voice is send back to remote location where it is delivered to the user sitting over remote location. It is similar to talking to someone over a phone call on speaker mode.

I am designed an amplifier using LM386 for speaker and it works perfectly. But i am confused over whether microphone will also record the sound coming out from the speaker and user over remote location will hear echo of his/her own voice.

My question is how to cancel the sound from speaker while recording using a microphone? Should i cancel them in hardware or in software?
How it can be done in hardware?

Comment: Using the *echo cancellation* algorithms. Google it.

Comment: A simple and somewhat effective hardware solution is to use a bidirectional or cardoid microphone, and orient it so that the speaker is in a deadzone.

Comment: If you can feed the signal used to drive the speaker to a circuit that has access to the microphone input, and if you can adequately model the microphone and speaker behaviors, then at first blush a simple cross-correlation function will magically develop a phase delay for you. With that in hand, you can subtract the interfering signal. But you need an automatic way to match signal amplitudes and although the microphone may be pretty good, the speaker is usually a significant distorting source and may need a good model. That, and more reasons, are why echo cancellation takes serious work.

Comment: @Dampmaskin: That is far too simplistic. The speaker fills the area with sound, and reverberation from walls and other nearby objects means that the microphone receives speaker sound from *many arbitrary* directions. Furthermore, the reverberaton changes when the relative positions of objects (including people) change, so any echo canceller *must* be adaptive.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I was replying to the OP: "How it can be done in hardware?" You're welcome to suggest an adaptive hardware solution. ;)

Comment: @Dampmaskin: My point is that your solution is simple and *not at all* effective. In other words, it isn't a solution, period.

Comment: @DaveTweed: You are right that it is not at all effective against acuostic echo in the room, but it can be effective against feedback. I'm pretty sure that a significant part of the percieved "echo" in this type of application is in fact delayed feedback, not actual acoustic echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very complex signal processing task known as "echo cancellation". Some open source voice encoders have it selectably built in (such as Speex). I believe that some Bluetooth hands-free devices have this too, if that is an option for your system.

Sidenote: It can actually be present at multiple locations in a voice chat (bluetooth hands-free, cell phone, telephone carrier, remote VoIP system, remote speakerphone) leading to large and annoying delays, since each echo cancellation step adds a small amount of delay.

To my knowledge this is not something that is available to simply 'plug in' very easily, unless you spend some big money.. but you might have luck looking into those open source voice encoders.

Answer (score 1):

- The easiest solution is either two mics in differential mode for high quality and cancel background noise or an electret with good noise cancellation properties for background. (Trial and error)
- However, mic must be close to mouth.
- Otherwise variable echo cancellation can get complex.